# How to merge conflicts in Monticello?

Tags: version-control, merge, smalltalk, pharo, monticello

How do you merge in Monticello? Seriously.

When I have a conflict I have a changes-like window, and when I select a conflicting method, I can click on arrows/ticks/crosses in conflicts, but it does not decrease the number of conflicts and so the `Merge` button stays disabled. How do I merge?

Comment: I found that a bit confusing as well when I last came across it, +1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to choose an integration option from the context menu right clicking in the conflict line.
there are also shortcuts cmd+c, cmd+g